# How to hide a specific attribute in variable product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My website is made on woocomerce, i have used 2 attributes, one is HSN code and second is colour, on my product page while displaying the Products, i only want the colour to be shown , but both the attributes of HSN and colour are showing on the product page, is there any way to display only the colour ,HSN code is important for all of my products

I have tried all the options available on woocomerce, not able to find the answer

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Product page editor, under Attributes, there is a checkbox for "Visible on the product page" under each attribute. You can uncheck the one for HSN codes.